# Fetch JackHenry Account ownership information

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I'm integrating against JackHenry's digital toolkit, where I'd like to retrieve account ownership information for KYC-related purposes. Specifically, for each account, I would like to know the following accountholder information:

1. Name
2. Address
3. Email (optional)
4. Phone (optional)

I've considered the following options:

1. Use the `GET /users/{userId}` [endpoint](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/user/details/#/User%20Functions/get_users__userId_).

   - Pros: Contains all the information that I need.
   - Cons: It pertains the authenticated user's information, which may not be the same as the accountholder's information. For example, if this account belongs to an LLC, I want the LLC's name/address etc., not the user's.
2. Use the `GET /users/{userId}/accounts` [endpoint](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/accounts/details/#/Account%20Information/get_users__userId__accounts)

   - Pros: Contains an `accountHolderName` field
   - Cons: Does not contain address/email/phone field.

Which API (or set of APIs) would you recommend using to retrieve the accountholder's ownership information?

Answer (score 0):

### The short answer

The Banno Digital Toolkit doesn't offer account *ownership* information via its Consumer API nor Admin API.

### The longer answer

From an account *ownership* perspective, it would be misleading to use any of the Digital Toolkit's APIs for that specific purpose (including the ones you've identified in your question).

The Banno digital banking UI doesn't know *who* owns an account, it simply knows that a given user has been *granted* access to view that particular account in the underlying *core*.

There can be a variety of reasons and relationships which influence why a user may be granted access to an account, but there isn't anything explicitly passed into Banno which would describe *ownership* per se.

Which means that the Banno Digital Toolkit wouldn't have a way to offer account ownership information either since the Digital Toolkit offers the same Consumer API and Admin API used by the Banno digital banking UI.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but then why does the API return the accountholder name, and not the remaining ownership information required by the institution when opening an account (e.g. address)?

Comment: In this case, that property was originally built for the Banno Online + Banno Mobile apps to display the account holder name in their UI. The property description is a hint at the history: _Name of the account holder (intended for display purposes only)_.